# File.Open() with PATH environment variable

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a CLI program that on an event, runs `Process.Start()` on a user-defined file. This respects `%PATH%`, but `File.Open()` does not.

Basically, when the program is launched, I run a variety of checks. One of the checks I want is that this file exists and can be opened by the current user, ala:

```
try
{
    fs = File.Open(Run, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    Run = args[++i];
}
catch(TheVariousExceptions){ .... }
finally
{
    if(fs != null)
        fs.Close();
}
```

The exceptions are also handled at the time of `Process.Start()`, but this may not be invoked until a while after, when the user might have configured the program and left it to run. So I'd like to first run the check like above. Problem is, it doesn't take `%PATH%` into account.

Any ideas?

Comment: Path only applies to files to run, not to files to open and read such as text files/word docs/databases etc.

Comment: @bugfinder It is a 'file to run'... a .exe usually. Maybe occasionally a .bat

Comment: Maybe you need a bit more code, but the file.open to me, is opening a file such as a text file etc

Comment: @BugFinder Then what would you suggest to do? I don't want to try to start the process at the beginning of the program because it's important that it's only started on an event.

Comment: Im not saying your process.start isnt right - but you havent posted that code.. but because you're testing it with file.open - that doesnt use paths.. surely, the process just wont start if it cant be used due to permissions, this is the simple check to do.

Comment: @BugFinder The `Process.Start()` code is irrelevant. Indeed the process won't start... when it finally fires the event. By which time it is too late to inform the user, because the program's been installed and configured and the server walked away from. The check needs to be immediately after run to prevent this scenario. I think if I can use `Process.Start()` in a `try/catch` at the start, and somehow sandbox it off so it never "appears" to run, this would be the best solution; but I'm still open to some solution to be able to use `File.Open()`

Comment: Then as Damien has said, you would need to itterate down the path yourself to use the method you had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it.

```
static Process TestProc = new Process();
static ProcessStartInfo TestProcStart = new ProcessStartInfo();
try
{
    TestProcStart.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    TestProcStart.FileName = args[++i];
    TestProc.StartInfo = TestProcStart;
    TestProc.Start();
    TestProc.Kill();
    Run = args[i];
}
catch(Win32Exception e)
{
    switch(e.NativeErrorCode)
    {
        case 2: Console.WriteLine("ERROR: File " + args[i] + " not found!"); return;
        case 5: Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Access denied to " + args[i] + "!"); return;
        default: Console.WriteLine("ERROR " + e.NativeErrorCode + ": " + e.Message); return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to do it manually.

You can use [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx) to retrieve `PATH`. Then, split it on `;`s and keep the result in a `List`. Then you'll have to `Combine` each path with the file name and perform your `File.Open` check on each combination that is produced.

Are you sure it's worth doing these checks?